# CSRF Token empty when the website is in maintenance mode

Tags: laravel, csrf

My goal is to still allow administrators to login to the website, even in maintenance mode.
However, when the website is in maintenance mode (using `php artisan down`), Laravel won't generate any CSRF Token.

`csrf_token()` is returning an empty string, and `csrf_field()` is returning `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="">`

This issue won't occur if the website is not in maintenance mode.

Is it possible to force the generation of the token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution which can fit for you is to disable csrf token for your admin route when maintenance mode is enabled

To do this open

`App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`

and add

```
protected $except = [
    '/your/route'
];
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to avoid disabling CSRF at all, but I guess it wont harm to disable it on the login form + admin pages (since nobody can craft a request for those, am I wrong?). Thank you!

Comment: You might want to do a little research to verify nothing bad will come of disabling CSRF

Comment: it's not good practice, but in this case it's fits the demands

Answer (score 1):

You might struggle as maintenance mode is purely meant to stop all traffic. You will have to create your own global middleware which checks if a value (possibly could be an env property) is set to determine if your own maintenance mode it on.

You can also say if a certain IP is used you can bypass the middleware.

Comment: Interesting solution. It's just weird that there isn't any option to enable back the token generation. (Also didn't find anything related to maintenance mode in Illuminate\Session\Store.php!) Thank you for this neat idea!